# Do you keep copies of your work?

Tags: work, samples, archive, backups

If so, what type? Do you save the final mix and a video file in a Pro Tools session?

Do you buy the DVD release or record it somehow?

Is it smart to keep a copy of everything you have ever worked on? Small and big?

Answer (score 6):

I save everything (and I mean EVERYTHING) for at least a few years. Every once in a while someone turns around and says that something needs to be change. After 3 years or so, I'll go through old material and cull it down to a set of stems that will give a reasonable amount of flexibility on the off chance that I need to do something with them.

Afterall, storage is CHEAP nowadays.

Comment: True! I think I'll do the same. That's exrtremely smart.

Answer (score 2):

I keep a copy of the ProTools mix session for each show and burn them to BluRay. I also keep the stems but in seperate sessions as I need to archive NTSC and PAL copies, the 24p masters are on the HDCAMSR Tapes.

I don't save any picture as if I need it I can digitise the tape if I need to.

Answer (score 2):

I keep absolutely everything I work on.  Older stuff is on DVD-Ram on the self, and lots of it is stored on a raw hard drive in a Hudzee box on my shelf.  Products that have been completed and released I try to get a final copy of, but sometimes I don't.  That's not as big of a deal to me as keeping my sessions and materials I used for the project.

Comment: @Colin - I've been looking at those Hudzee containers. Are you happy with them?

Comment: @Shaun - they're awesome!  A bunch of other guys here use them too.  I've heard nothing but good reviews!

Answer (score 1):

I save everything because I often want to know how I did something.  I need a better method than offloading the project files onto a CD, though.

Answer (score 1):

At the day job, I pretty much have to keep everything because one never knows when a client is going to come back after 3 years and want to resurrect an old project. I think I have every session going back to when I switched from Sonic Solutions to ProTools in 2001. For my independent sound design work I also try to keep everything, though there are some projects where I ask the client to purchase a hard drive, and I let them be responsible for the assets. As far as released copies, I like to have at least one copy around. It's something I can show to my family so they have some context for what I do!